# Build in Jenkins fails when gcc finds errors

Tags: gcc, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

---

Hello people

I'm trying to build a C project using Jenkins. This project has many source files (over 500), so I'm doing this step by step.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all the errors and warnings into a file, this file is useful, because after that I need these results for Jenkins "Compiler Warning Plugin".

To get all the information I need I'm running the following command as a "Build Step":

```
gcc -Wall path/to/my/source/files.c 2>report.xml
```

After that, I have other configurations and build steps, but when I execute the build, it fails because of the error messages triggered by gcc. And the rest of the steps an other configurations are never executed.

The thing is, if I execute the same gcc command, to the same files, but outside Jenkins, I mean in a typically Linux terminal, I don't receive any message about failure. The xml file with warnings and errors output is generated and the Linux terminal finish the task without complaint

How can I achieve the same behavior in Jenkins and not receive a build failure message? Thnaks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the `gcc` command returns an error code to the shell that calls it. You can force this to true by doing something like

```
gcc -Wall path/to/my/source/files.c 2>report.xml || true
```

Comment: Yes, that works for me. And I found another possible solution `gcc -Wall path/to/my/source/files.c 2>report.xml &>/dev/null`